# Laptop fan turns off and on while doing nothing

Tags: windows-10, laptop, fan, speedfan

So I brought a laptop couple of months ago. And it was functioning fine. however, I noticed the fan just got a little bit louder. Basically you can hear it in a quite room, when I first bought I couldn't. Anyway, my question is that sometimes I have Access open and only access or say some program. Then I hear the fan stop spinning and after 5 seconds it goes back on. It does that sometimes when I am not using the computer (I keep it on while I write what I found on paper). So guys please help me what is the issue here? 
I looked on task manager while I am using programs and I am not over using anything.  My computer specification are:

- Intel Core i7-6500U
- NVIDIA GeForce 940 with 2GB of Dedicated VRAM (Not used this graphics card since I brought the laptop)
- 8Gb RAM
- 1TB Hard Drive

What I noticed also while I am writing this, it's running normal. But it's weird also because I run Ubuntu on (Virtual box) the fan does sometimes stop and start again. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Does it also only intermittently spin when the laptop is under heavy load? When it does spin under low loads, does it spin fast or do you think it's just spinning a little? If it keeps alternating between off and spinning full power there's probably something wrong, otherwise, it might be the case that the fan stops when below a certain temperature, and your computer is running right around that limit.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a short, try assembling your laptop referring to the manual, or change the fan, I think it's burned out.